# Simulate a another button postback inside a jQuery dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms, modal-dialog

I have the following ASPX page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.6.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'Ok': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        __doPostBack('TreeNew', '');
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    ;
                }
            });
        });
        function ShowDialog() {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="TreeNew" runat="server" Text="Nuevo" OnClientClick="ShowDialog(); return false;"/>
        <asp:Label ID="Message" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <div id="dialog" title="Create new user">
            <p id="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="ContentTypeList" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Text</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Image</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Audio</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Video</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user click on TreeNew button appears the modal dialog, then he/she choose an option an click Ok button to do a postback.

I need that the server side execute TreeNew_Click method: How can I do that?

If I use __doPostBack('TreeNew', '') it throws me the following error: "Object expected".

**UPDATE:**
I found the origin for the error: the function **__doPostBack** is not defined. I'm not going to delete the question because I think Chris Clark's answer is so interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule, if you find yourself ever typing the text "__doPostBack(...", you should re-evaluate your approach.

In this case, you should just put a server-side asp.net button inside the div that you are turning into the dialog and use that instead of the generates jQuery button. That way the postback code will get wired up for you. There is one caveat however - when jQuery turns your div (I'm going to assuming it's a div) into a dialog, it *rips the div out of the form element*. That means you have to attach it BACK to the form BEFORE the postback occurs. You can do that in the close function of the dialog. The postback will then occur properly.

If you really want to use the generated jQuery OK button, you have a couple of options. First, you can slap a server-side asp.net button on the page and hide it, then call the asp.net button's click event from the OK button's code. Second, you can emit a javascript function form the server using Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference that will contain the __doPostBack code that you were trying to hand-write above. Then call that emitted function from the OK button's JS code.